# File Extension only changed in Console.log

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the extension of a file to be .zip and by hacking together some over stackoverflow answers I have cobbled together some code that sorta works, when logged to the console it shows the output I want but does nothing to the actual files https://gyazo.com/9f953285e5076dfccb1a885d1d86d4fa

```
const directory = 'C:/Users/cszoc/Downloads/pa_mods/mods/'
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(directory, (_err, _files) => {
    _files.forEach(_files => {
        const reext = _files.substr(0, _files.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".zip"
        console.log(reext);
    });
});
```

Comment: *but does nothing to the actual files* What were you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something like:

```
fs.rename(_files, reext, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Rename complete!');
})
```

to the end to actually move the file.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Comment: thanks, I don't know how to code at all you saved me but after using mozilla's javascript documentation I have created this https://github.com/Fisheiyy/file-extension-changer